# NG Table no works with just 1 record

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, angularjs

I´ve a problem about angularJS.

My ng-table no works when database comes just 1 record.
When is loaded 2 or more records works.

**Browser error console:**
Error: [orderBy:notarray] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/orderBy/notarray?p0=%7B%22clienteID%22%3A…clienteNome%22%3A%22Nicolas%22%2C%22clienteConta%22%3A%229.9999999E7%22%7D
    at Error (native)
    at

**MY HTML:**

```html
<table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-striped" show-filter="true">
                <tr ng-repeat="cliente in data">
                       <td title="'ID'" filter="{ clienteID: 'number'}" sortable="'clienteID'">
                        {{cliente.clienteID}}
                    </td>
                    <td title="'Cliente'" filter="{ clienteNome: 'text'}" sortable="'clienteNome'">
                        {{cliente.clienteNome}}
                    </td>
                    <td><a ng-click="editUser(user.id)" class="btn btn-small btn-primary">Editar</a></td>
                    <td><a ng-click="deleteClienteById(cliente.clienteID)" class="btn btn-small btn-danger">Excluir</a></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

**MY CONTROLLER:**

```
angular.module('ProjetoAngularClient').controller('clienteController',
        function($scope,$filter,NgTableParams,clienteService) {

        clienteService.getAllClientes().success(function(response){
        $scope.clientes = response.cliente;
        table();
        });

        function getAll(){
            clienteService.getAllClientes().success(function(response){
                $scope.clientes = null;
                $scope.clientes = response.cliente;
                $scope.tableParams.reload();
                });
        }

          function table(){
                $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({
                    page: 1,
                    count:10
                }, {
                    total: $scope.clientes.length, 
                    getData: function ($defer, params) {
                           $scope.data = params.sorting() ? $filter('orderBy')($scope.clientes, params.orderBy()) : $scope.clientes;
                           $scope.data = params.filter() ? $filter('filter')($scope.data, params.filter()) : $scope.data;
                           $scope.data = $scope.data.slice((params.page() - 1) * params.count(), params.page() * params.count());
                           $defer.resolve($scope.data);
                        }
                });  
          };

            $scope.deleteClienteById = function(clienteID) {
            clienteService.deleteClienteById(clienteID);
            getAll();
        };
});
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need an array in all cases. However `$scope.clientes = response.cliente;` sets `$scope.clientes` to one single client.

I don't fully understand your program logic. At first you seem to load from `clienteService.getAllClientes()` and then call `getAll();` via `table()` to again load `clienteService.getAllClientes()`.

A quick fix would be to test if `response.cliente` is an array, and if not, assign it like `$scope.clientes = [response.cliente];`

However, I think your backend should be fixed to always return an array.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for help!The error occours cause my service returns just 1 record and JS dont understand like Array....Ignore getAll method...

Comment: If it solves your problem, please accept the answer via the checkmark so others who find this question see there's a working solution (and also because I get a couple of points)